# OpenGL ES God Ray Precision error

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I have encountered the following (i think) precision error.

[image]

[image]

My source of inspiration was:
http://fabiensanglard.net/lightScattering/

On the PC everything works fine, but on android it shows those weird squares.

I had the same problem with a procedurally masked sprite. When the radius of the circle was getting too big i had the same error so i changed the mask from a shader radius uniform to a texture mask uniform, so i guess there is a precision problem.

This guy here had the same problem but unfortunately i can't see the answer.

http://community.arm.com/thread/4024

The code adapted to OpenGL ES is the following:

```
#version 100

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D tex_diff;
uniform vec2 light_on_screen;

varying vec2 texture_coord;

const int NUM_SAMPLES = 128;

void main()
{
    const float exposure = 0.0225;
    const float decay = 0.95;
    const float density = 0.95;
    const float weight = 3.75;

    // Inner used valuesa
    vec2 deltaTextCoord = vec2(texture_coord.st - light_on_screen.xy);
    vec2 textCoo = texture_coord.st;
    deltaTextCoord *= 1.0 / float(NUM_SAMPLES) * density;
    float illuminationDecay = 1.0;

    vec4 c = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for(int i=0; i < NUM_SAMPLES ; i++)
    {
        textCoo -= deltaTextCoord;

        textCoo.s = clamp(textCoo.s, 0.0, 1.0);
        textCoo.t = clamp(textCoo.t, 0.0, 1.0);

        vec4 sample = texture2D(tex_diff, textCoo);

        sample *= illuminationDecay * weight;

        c += sample;

        illuminationDecay *= decay;
    }

    c *= exposure;

    c.r = clamp(c.r, 0.0, 1.0);
    c.g = clamp(c.g, 0.0, 1.0);
    c.b = clamp(c.b, 0.0, 1.0);
    c.a = clamp(c.a, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = c;
}
```

Showing the whole engine is useless since it's huge. All the shader input is correct, the coordinates are correct, the only problem is the inner shader computation.

Anybody encountered this or has any ideas for any workarounds?

Scanned the whole net for a solution for this, and i couldn't seem to find one. Any can point me in the right direction? Or maybe someone encountered this type of error in a different context or in a different shader? Maybe i can apply the same workaround here too.

Comment: I'd add a word of warning that this technique is insanely expensive for mobile unless you are rendering at a really low resolution (most high-end content will use less than 10 texture lookups per on-screen pixel on average, you are using 128 texture lookups per pixel just for this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated with a minor fix:

[image]

[image]

Yes, the problem was:

'textCoo -= deltaTextCoord';

Due to the fp precision the error accumulated grows to something like 2.7%. Calculating it each loop instead of subtracting a delta fixes a big part of the problem.

As for optimization, i am using some techniques, got a reasonable 40fps.

See this post, i asked the same question here:
http://community.arm.com/message/29658?et=watches.email.thread#29658

For optimizations used see this post:
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/670346-opengl-es-god-ray-precision-error/

Answer (score 1):

One of the common differences is the use of mediump on mobile (which is commonly fp16) vs desktop (which often does not implement fp16, and just promotes to fp32).

If you use highp does it look any better?

Comment: Note that If you are trying to run this fragment shader on a Mali 400 GPU then setting precision to highp will not work, because this specific GPU cannot handle highp in fragments (it can in vertex, not in fragments ...)

There is no solution to this sadly, the only thing you may try to do is to try using "big values" until the very last moment which may keep precision a bit longer, like described in the arm community link.

On Adreno / Tegra / PowerVR GPUs it should work if you change precision to highp.